# Is there a word or a phrase for 'the ability to not get annoyed by someone who overly loves you'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, emotions

When someone loves me a lot, I tend to start taking them for granted, and even get annoyed but there are people who do not get irritated by this at all. Is there a word for this ability?

For example, usage:
She loved him to bits, and he was able to take it all in gracefully, he was ____.

Comment: This is a weird question, so to not get annoyed by someone who overly loves you even though they take you for granted?  A “doormat”?

Comment: @RLicens, basically the ability not to treat people like a doormats, even if it is easy to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I would've thought that 'Patience' was the word :-)

Comment: I'm looking for something more specific